# programing advice for a class example

Tags: java, swing, loops, joptionpane

i am a basic programing student and i need help on how to make a particular program. 
The scenario is: people go in and out of an event and i need to keep track of them. the limit of people allowed is 100. People can come alone or en masse. As people go in and out the total should change. people should be denied access after limit is reached.

everything will be going into JOptionPane.

not sure if im looking at the best site for help but, any advice would help.

i know i will make a while loop for this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class HwTwoPt2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int enter, exit, total;
         int maxCapacity = 106;
         int count = 0;
         int groupAmt = 0;


         while(count != maxCapacity){
            groupAmt = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter total amount in the group: "));


             }
         }

    }
```

Comment: Why must it go into a JOptionPane?  This code does nothing as written.  Better to use a text-only interface until you get the logic right, then add the GUI.  You're making a classic new programming mistake: putting everything into a main method.  Encapsulate it into an object that you can test and reuse.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Can you give us more information on what you have issues with?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to deny people access once a limit has been hit you'll want to change your while loop to something like:

```
while(count < maxCapacity)
```

If you go with != maxCapacity, a value of 107 would pass and allow people entry.

You will also want to verify groupAmt before adding it to maxCapacity.

```
if((count + groupAmt) < maxCapacity)
{
    count += groupAmt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to encapsulate all this into an object.  Java's an object-oriented language.  Better to get used to thinking in terms of encapsulation and information hiding early.

Something like this:

```
public class CapacityTracker {
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_CAPACITY = 100;
    private int currentCapacity;
    private int maxCapacity;

    public CapacityTracker() { 
        this(DEFAULT_MAX_CAPACITY);
    }

    public CapacityTracker(int maxCapacity) { 
        this.maxCapacity = ((maxCapacity <= 0) ? DEFAULT_MAX_CAPACITY : maxCapacity);
        this.currentCapacity = 0;
    }

    public int getCurrentCapacity() { return this.currentCapacity; }

    public void addAttendees(int x) { 
        if (x > 0) {
            if ((this.currentCapacity+x) > this.maxCapacity) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("max capacity exceeded");
            } else {
                this.currentCapacity += x;
            }         
        }
    }
}
```

I'd keep adding methods to make this more convenient for me to use.

I might create a custom CapacityExceededException as well.

Comment: i have thought about using objects, not very familiar with them. but ive asked to use them and he said no. apparently its to advance... -_-
@duffymo

Comment: Maybe someday.  Right now you have nothing.